# Get form identity when validation fails

Tags: laravel, validation

How can I get the form identity when validation fails? I need to use it for an open modal, but I can't identify which modal should open.

I need something like the following, but it's not working.

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator->errors()->add('form', 'some_form_name');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `identity`?

Answer (score 1):

If by `identity` you meant `id` attribute of a form html element, then there's no direct way built into Laravel to accomplish this, but..

You can pass the `id` inside a hidden input and then access it via `$request->the_hidden_input`

Answer (score 0):

Forgot add parent::failedValidation($validator);

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator->errors()->add('form', 'modal_'.request()->id);

    parent::failedValidation($validator);
}
```

and

```
<script>

$(function () {

    @if (isset($errors) && count($errors) && $errors->has('form'))

        $('#{{ $errors->first('form') }}').modal('show');

    @endif

});

</script>
```